# how to get the control added at the specified row and column in window control Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

how to get the control added at the specified row and column in window control Grid(not gridview or datagrid)? in C#

Suppose we know which row and column the control is located, how to get the control by grid row and column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this with a LINQ query easily enough:

```
public IEnumerable<UIElement> GetElementsAtPosition(Grid grid, int row, int column)
{
    return grid.Children.OfType<UIElement>().Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == row && Grid.GetColumn(c) == column);
}
```

This needs to return an `IEnumerable`, as there can be multiple controls at a given row & column intersection.  This is also not very reliable if you are doing Row/Column spanning (it won't catch the case where an element starts at a different row or column, and spans into it).

**EDIT**  Thanks @wpfwannabe for the proper LINQ operator required to make this work.  It still boggles my mind that UIElementCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<UIElement>.

Comment: Thanks.
Shall I add using namespace System.Linq or ...?

Comment: I have the System.Linq, but still have trouble with grid.Children.Where

what I miss please? Thanks

Comment: System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection'

Comment: Try `grid.Children.OfType<UIElement>.Where(c => Grid.GetRow(c) == row && Grid.GetColumn(c) == column)`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I always forget that collection doesn't implement IEnumerable<UIElement>  Thanks @wpfwannabe for the solution.